# Filter and modify elements in boost::multi_index from an equal_range query

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

I have a `boost::multi_index` with a `hashed_non_unique` view. What I would like to accomplish is, given a key in that view, use

```
pair<myIter, myIter> iterRange = myView.equal_range(key);
for (myIter iter = iterRange.first; iter != iterRange.second; ++iter) {
    // ...
}
```

to find all elements associated with that key. Then, run these elements through a filter

```
bool filter(Element e) { /* some filtering logic*/ }
```

and modify the filtered results with a modifier

```
void modifier(Element e) { /* modify the elements with e.g. myView.modify() */ }
```

However, simply putting these pieces together doesn't work since modifying the elements results in reordering of the multi_index, which renders my iterRange invalid.

What would be the correct way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some comments to your proposed solution:

- `BMIter` is not special as you seem to imply, but merely the iterator associated to the first index of the container. Note that this will be the same as `myIter` when `myView` happens to be this first index.
- Nevertheless, iterators of hashed indices [are not invalidated by insertions or modifications](https://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/indices.html#guarantees), so you're safe. In fact, you could have defined `iters` as a `vector<myIter>` and store the iterators directly without any further conversion --you're still achieving the intended effect of not being affected by potential reorderings after modification.
- Even though what you're doing is perfectly fine, if you're into squeezing some additional performance note that modification of elements in a hashed index [does not change the underlying ordering when the key remains equivalent](https://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/hash_indices.html#modify), so the only way a reordering can possibly affect you when traversing a range of equivalent keys is when a modified element jumps directly *after* the range (i.e, just before `iterRange.second`). With this mind, you can spare the `iters` trick as follows:

```
for (myIter iter = iterRange.first; iter != iterRange.second; ) {
    auto nextIter = std::next(iter);
    if (filter(*iter)) {
        myView.modify(iter, modifier);
        if (nextIter != iterRange.second && std::next(iter) == iterRange.second)
            iterRange.second = iter;
    }
    iter = nextIter;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Joaquin for your answer! Will the solution you proposed work for ordered indices too? The modification I'm trying to do indeed changes the ordering in my current view.

Comment: I also have a question about your statement that a reordering can only affect the traversal if the modified element jumps right after the range: what if it jumps to some point within the range, but after the current iterator? Wouldn't that result in this element being modified again later in the loop? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to clarify, my previous question was about the case of ordered indices. There is a view of my multi_index based on weak_ptrs and using hashed index would not be a good idea.

Comment: The solution would also work for ordered indices, as these too keep position after modification when the key remains equivalent. So, there is no possibility that an element hops somewhere else *inside* the range after modification.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the answer myself. Instead of simply modifying the elements inside the for loop, we need to cache the elements first and modify them later to avoid altering the ordering. The trick here is, instead of caching the iterators to this specific view, cache instead iterators to the elements themselves, i.e.

```
vector<BMIIter> iters;
for (myIter iter = iterRange.first; iter != iterRange.second; ++iter) {
    if (filter(*iter)) {
        iters.push_back(myBMI.iterator_to(*iter));
    }
}
for (auto iter : iters) {
    myBMI.modify(iter, modifier);
}
```

Note that `BMIIter` and `myIter` are different iterator types - the former is an iterator to the element itself, while the latter is iterator specific to myView. Modifying elements in the multi_index invalidates the latter, but the former still holds valid even after reordering happened.

Comment: Rather than `myBMI.iterator_to(*iter)`, you can use `myBMI.project(iter)`